# Can you explain why this index of a Python list of tuples gives 15 as an answer?

Tags: python, list, indexing, tuples

```
_magnitude_list = [(0,''), (3, 'thousand'), (6, 'million'),
                (9, 'billion'), (12, 'trillion'), (15, '')]

index1 = _magnitude_list[-1]
index2 = _magnitude_list[0]
index3 = _magnitude_list[-1][0]
```

index1 gives an output of (15, '')

index2 gives an output of (0, '')

index3 gives an output of 15 and not (15, '')(0, ''). Why is this so?

Comment: `_magnitude_list[-1]` is `(15, '')`. So `_magnitude_list[-1][0]` is `(15, '')[0]`, which is `15`.

Comment: @Paulina Mensah with `[-1]` you access last element of the list that is tuple `(15, '')`, and with `[-1][0]` you access last element from list and first element in tuple that is `15`.

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi got it. Thanks!

Comment: @khelwood understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negative indexes in Python ([link](https://www.i2tutorials.com/what-are-negative-indexes-and-why-are-they-used/#:%7E:text=Python%20programming%20language%20supports%20negative,from%20where%20the%20array%20ends.)) mean that you start from the end of the list, so `_magnitude_list[-1]` will give you the last element of the list.

Since you have a multidimensional structure here - list of 2-element tuples, `_magnitude_list[-1]` will give you the whole last tuple, and `_magnitude_list[-1][0]` will give you only the first element in the last tuple.

Similar for the 0 value for the index - it will give you the first element of the list, in your case `_magnitude_list[0]` will give you the whole first tuple in the list.

Answer (score 0):

It is so because you access the 0-element of the last element. In your example `index3 = _magnitude_list[-1][0]` is the same as `index3 = index1[0]`.

If you want the first and the last item of the list you can access this with `_magnitude_list[slice(0,len(_magnitude_list),len(_magnitude_list)-1)]`